# Dropdown Menu w/ css

Tags: html, css

Could someone help me figure out how to style this code in css to show a drop down menu? Here's what I got so far, but I don't know what to do after. I appreciate your help, thank you.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Programs</a></li>
            <ul class="drop-down-menu">
                <li><a href="">Personal Trainer</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Group Workout</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


nav{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
    list-style-type: none;
    word-spacing: 30px;
    font-family: 'karla', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.62);

nav a{
    color: #F4F4F4;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.drop-down-menu{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your wanting the dropdown menu to dropdown do not set the list-items (li) under the un-ordered list (ul) to "display: inline-block. This will display the list-items side by side.

Also for your dropdown box you will have to state the border (if wanted), padding, margin etc too.

```
.drop-down-menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #yourcolor;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: (how many pixels between the dropdown and your page
     ^ Best to add this only if position is absolute
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
```

}

State if you need help with your javascript